# python pandas dataframe transform based on tag/column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two pandas dataframes

```
df1=
           selected0 selected1
2017-01-01  product1  product2
2017-01-02  product1  product2
2017-01-03  product3  product4

df2 = 
            selected0 selected1
2017-01-01       0.2       0.3
2017-01-02       0.3       0.4
2017-01-03       0.5       0.6
```

Now I would like to transform these two dataframes into a single dataframe that looks like the following

```
             product1 product2 product3 product4
2017-01-01      0.2      0.3      NaN      NaN
2017-01-02      0.3      0.4      NaN      NaN
2017-01-03      NaN      NaN      0.5      0.6
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this without looping through every single row in the dataframe? thank you very much

Comment: notice the difference in columns name in the resulting dataframe, the number of columns on the resulting dataframe depends on the content of the first dataframe, so dont' know if join would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform both data frames to long format and then merge based on the date and select*, and then transform the result back to wide format:

```
(df1.stack().to_frame("Product")               # reshape df1 to long format
    .join(df2.stack().rename("Value"))         # reshape df2 to long format and join with df1
    .reset_index(level = 1, drop = True)       # drop the original column names
    .pivot(columns="Product", values="Value")) # reshape to wide format
```

[image]

Comment: am getting a merging with both multi-indexes is not implemented error in pandas when doing the join(), am on pandas 0.18.1

Comment: If `join` doesn't work, you can convert the multi index to normal columns and then use `merge`. `(df1.stack().rename("Product").reset_index().merge(df2.stack().rename("Value").reset_index()).drop("level_1", axis = 1).pivot("level_0", "Product", "Value"))`

Comment: never mind, my multi indicies had different names for the two dataframe, this is very elegant and pythonic in my opinion, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

using the dreaded loop

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index, columns=np.unique(df1.values))

for (d, c), v in df2.stack().iteritems():
    df3.set_value(d, df1.get_value(d, c), v)

df3
```

[image]